# Repetir números ímpares com do while

Tags: c++

Oi,

Preciso fazer um código, dentro de um `switch`, que reproduza todos os números ímpares de 0 a 200, com a estrutura de repetição `do while`. Procurei no google e só achei com for. Já tentei colocar o "impar0a200%2!=0" dentro do do, mas o problema persiste; fica repetindo todos os números de 0 a 200, incluindo os pares. O Código está assim:

```
case '3': {    // com problemas!!

    impar0a200%2!=0;

    do
    {
        cout<<"\n Os números a seguir são os ímpares entre 0 e 200:  " <<impar0a200;
        impar0a200++;
    }   while (impar0a200<=200);


    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A verificação `impar0a200%2 != 0` está correta, basta então utilizar essa condição em um `if` e sendo verdadeira, exibir o número.

```
if (impar0a200 % 2 != 0) {
  cout << impar0a200 << endl;
}
```

Essa condição deve ficar dentro do seu bloco de `do/while`, exibindo assim todos os números ímpares até o final do loop.

---

Veja um exemplo utilizando parte de seu código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char teste = '3';
  int impar0a200 = 0;

  switch (teste) {
    case '3': {         
      cout << "\nOs números a seguir são os ímpares entre 0 e 200: " << endl;

      do {
        if (impar0a200 % 2 != 0) {
          cout << impar0a200 << endl;
        }

        impar0a200++;
      } while (impar0a200 <= 200);

      break;
    }
  }

}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PopularCleverPrediction

Comment: Muito grato. Estava faltando colocar o if, este era o principal. Obrigado Daniel Mendes.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso específico poderia simplificar para:

```
case '3': {
    impar0a200 = 1;
    cout<<"\n Os números a seguir são os ímpares entre 0 e 200:  " << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "\t" << impar0a200;
        impar0a200 += 2;
    } while (impar0a200 <= 200);
    break;
}
```